# How to clone cloned DOM objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

I have `<div class="OptionRow">`s followed by a `<a class="AddGroup">`

Inside the `.OptionRow`s, I have an X to remove that row.

The .AddGroup works fine until I X the original element that was cloned. Here's my code for the cloning and the X

```
$('.AddGroup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings('.OptionRow:first').clone(true, true).hide().insertBefore($this).fadeIn();
});
$('.CloseGroup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.OptionRow').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: inspect html of the page before clicking `X` and compare between the original and the clone html.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/capo64/9XJXc/

Comment: Thanks, microprocessor. I realized I had it inserting the clones inside the `<div>` that contained `.AddGroup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Microprocessor's suggestion, I examined the HTML and realized the `.OptionRow` clone was being inserted into the wrong place in the DOM. I solved the problem by using `.insertBefore($this.parent())` instead of `.insertBefore($this)`. Thanks @Microprocessor, I don't know why I didn't do that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The clone wont have the handlers that the original had.

Try using `.live('click', function(e){...})` for your click handlers which might fix the issue

Comment: he's using `.clone(true, true)` which according to the docs _does_ copy event handlers.